# Wordpress User Management Departmental Managers

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

In wordpress is it possible to departmentalise user accounts and then have a departmental manager oversea those accounts in same department but not other departments?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could.  I had done something similar using the [Eyes-Only plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/eyes-only-user-access-shortcode/).

Create a user type for each department.
Create an architecture for each department.
 - Menus
 - Pages
 - Custom post types
Select department managers
Create a query where department-admin can only see users of the same department.
This does require extensive work to get cross departmental work to function correctly.